# How to call Doctrine CacheProvider function in Laravel 4 Controller

Tags: symfony, namespaces, doctrine, laravel, laravel-4

I have seen some useful functions like the following in

`vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php` of laravel 4 installation.

```
public function flushAll()
{
    return $this->doFlush();
}
```

How can I call this function from my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked in Laravel Forum and here also, but no response!
Luckily I have derived solution for my question.

The `Composer` vendor have a `class autoload map` file which have an array with all class names with their namespace.
This file will be updated in all instance of `composer install` or `composer update` which will be prepeded by `composer dump-autoload` command.
If I am making a class somewhere, I have to execute the `php artisan dump-autoload` command to properly auto-load them.
So here in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, we have reference to all vendor classes including `Symfony` and `Doctrine`.
And the entry for the `Doctrine Cache Provider` will be,

```
'Doctrine\\Common\\Cache\\CacheProvider' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php'
```

Here I can see which file it is, and what will be the namespace.

Now we can call functions by using the namespace,

```
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider as DoctrineCache;

DoctrineCache::flushAll();
```

And also we can add this in `providers` array with `app.php`